# DNN module permissions - superuser only?

Tags: dotnetnuke

i've created a simple DNN module using MVC (based on the Christoc.com DNN 8 MVC module template from nuget), with a custom ControlKey. The purpose of this custom ControlKey is to call a specific MVC Action. For this exmaple I'll call this ControlKey "DoIt".

So, I define the ControlKey in the .dnn file:

```
<moduleControl>
    <controlKey>DoIt</controlKey>
    <controlSrc>MyApp.Modules.TestModule.Controllers/DoIt/DoIt.mvc</controlSrc>
    <supportsPartialRendering>False</supportsPartialRendering>
    <controlTitle>DoIt</controlTitle>
    <controlType>View</controlType>
    <iconFile />
    <helpUrl />
    <viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
    <supportsPopUps>True</supportsPopUps>
</moduleControl>
```

The View of the module only contains a link to the custom ControlKey, formatted using NavigateURL, like so:

http://dnndev.me/TestPage/tabid/89/ctl/DoIt//mid/450/Default.aspx

When logged in as a SuperUser account, this link works and correctly executes the DoIt action.
But, when logged in as a Non-SuperUser account, even as Administrator, I get an Access Denied message.

I've tried to adjust the module and page permissions, (either inherited from the page, or at the module itself), but I can't get it to with with non-SuperUser accounts.

What I am missing? Do I need to set the permissions for this custom ControlKey somewhere?
Is there a way to find out what permission is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume since your default view works that you have an MVC controller (DnnController) name DoItController with an action method called DoIt() as well as a default view action called Index() (or something similar).

Try using the MVC Url helper to link to your DoIt action from your default view (Index.cshtml).

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DoIt", "DoIt", new {ctl = "DoIt", itemId = item.ItemId})">Do It!</a>
```

The Url.Action takes as arguments:

- Action name (ie: DoIt)
- Controller name (ie: DoIt)
- routeValues (ie: ctl=[Control Key], [otherQS args])

The rendered href looks like this:

http://801.dnndev.me/TestPage/ctl/DoIt/mid/437/controller/DoIt/action/DoIt